# Angular UI modal and ng-messages not working

Tags: angularjs

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/7Kv8qrJBlGJ2xpiommDF?p=preview) I have a field validated with `ng-messages` on Angular ui Modal. The field on the form is required, but if I start typing a value it shows incorrectly the required error message. Why is that?

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtl">

   <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">

        <form name="form1" ng-submit="submitForm(form1)" novalidate>

            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">The Title</h4>
            </div>
                Enter userid  

                 <input type="text" name="userid" ng-model="userid" required />
                 <div ng-show="form1.$dirty" ng-messages="form1.userid.$error" style="color:red">
                    <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>
                 </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>

        </form>
    </script>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('myCtl', function($scope,$uibModal) {

      $scope.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
          animation: false,
          templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
          scope: $scope
        });

        $scope.submitForm = function(form) {
          alert ("form valid = " + form.$valid);
        };    
});
```

Comment: First obvious problem (I didn't go further): you're not using coherent versions for angular and angular-messages: 1.4.8 and 1.5.0-rc.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized the problem: I forgot to declare ngMessages like so

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap','ngMessages']);
```

Angular silently ignores this error